# MySQL: using main query variable on sub-sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create query that will show me table of stock, name of the stock, id, date, url, price and list of prices from the last 2 weeks.

For the 14 days history I used sub-query with group_concat on the select.

**But when I use group_concat it's return all results and ignore my limit, so I created another sub-query that will be the 14 prices and the group_concat will make it a list.**

The table 'record_log' is records for all stocks:
parent_stock_id - the actual stock this line belongs
price - the price
search_date - date of the price

The second table is 'stocks':
id - id of the stock
name, market_volume....

**Here is the problem:**
In the sub-sub-query (last line of the SELECT), when i'm filtering parent_stock_id=stocks.id he don't recognize the stocks.id because it belongs to the main query.
**How can I take the stock_id from top and pass it to the sub-sub-query? or maybe another idea?**

```
SELECT
    stocks.id AS stock_id,
    record_log.price AS price,
    record_log.search_date,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(price) FROM (SELECT price FROM record_log WHERE parent_stock_id=stocks.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 14) AS nevemind) AS history
FROM stocks
INNER JOIN record_log ON stocks.id = record_log.parent_stock_id
WHERE
    record_log.another_check !=0
```

Thank you!

*--- I'm are not really using it for stocks, it's just was the easiest way to explain :)*

Comment: Is  `WHERE AND record_log.another_check !=0` correct?

Comment: @daniel.shih it was with another line, I removed the "AND". it's not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `substring_index()` and eliminate the extra subquery:

```
SELECT s.id AS stock_id, rl.price AS price, rl.search_date,
       (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 14)
        FROM record_log rl2
        WHERE rl2.parent_stock_id = s.id 
       ) AS history
FROM stocks s INNER JOIN
     record_log rl
     ON s.id = rl.parent_stock_id
WHERE rl.another_check <> 0;
```

Note that MySQL has a settable limit on the length of the `group_concat()` intermediate result (`group_concat_max_len`).  This parameter is defaulted to 1,024.

Comment: Thank you! 'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is definitely what I was need :)